# System gets stuck while running windows phone emulator

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-7, windows-phone-7.1

I am developing an application for Windows Phone in Visual studio 2010 ultimate using wp7.1 SDK in Windows 7 32 bit and 3GB RAM. My system often gets stuck and then restarts sometimes when I run the application on wp7 Emulator (2 or 3 times an hour). Before restart it displays the message: "Display driver stopped responding and recovered" and leads to a blue screen displaying "some lines with Contact system admin".

Comment: I dont know what causes your problem, but do you have a wp7-device to test on? I find it much better to test on a real device, and when you have a nearly finished app its often crucial to have one to test on (especially for performance)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why, will need more details. Try installing the 7.1.1 update for the SDK, it is meant for low profile devices, but I am just hoping this will resolve your issues too.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29233

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Just start your sdk installer. There will be a option of repair of deleat. I repaired my sdk first but it still did not work. I then deleted my sdk and reinstalled it. Worked like a charm.

But you must you know that I was not able to delete my sdk too. My antivirus was doing something wrong and stopping the uninstall of my sdk. So I had to delete my antivirus... than my sdk. Than reinstall the sdk, reinstall the antivirus.

It all worked great after.